# How to bind kendo telrick grid dynamicale using mvc?iam new to mvc i dont know where iam going wrong

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

**This is the model part:- I have taken one list and string list for column value and string for column hearder**

```
 public class MRAprofileGridNew
    {
        public string DBColumnName { get; set; }
        public List<string> DBColumnvalue { get; set; }


    }
```

**This is CONTROLLER parts:-model is return over here**

```
public ActionResult RiskScorePatientData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string ACOName)
        {
            return Content(reportRepository.MedicalRiskScorePatientData(User.EmailId, ACOName).KendoJsonResult(request), "application/json");
        }
```

**View Part:- Her i want to bind the data dynamicale here i have struck how to bind data dynamicale**

```
 @*@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
    {*@
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Guardian.Core.Model.ViewModels.MRAprofileGridNew>()
                        .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table table-condensed Patient-Grid" })
                      .Name(gridId)
                .ToolBar(tb =>
                {
                    tb.Excel().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right " });

                })

.Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            //    foreach (var ColumnName in Model)
                            //    {

                            //        columns.Bound(gl => gl.DBColumnvalue).Title(ColumnName.DBColumnName).Width(200).Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
                            //    }


                            columns.Bound(team => team.DBColumnName).Title("Team Name");
                            columns.Bound(team => team.DBColumnvalue);

                            //foreach (var tem in Model)
                            //{
                            //    string blabal = tem.DBColumnName.ToString();
                            //    columns.Template(gl => gl.DBColumnvalue[0]).Title(blabal).Width(100);
                            //}

                            //columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(90);
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(90);
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.HICN).Title("HICN").Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text text-left" });
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.year).Title("Year").Width(50).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text text-right" });
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.ProviderName).Title("Provider Name").Width(200);
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.ACOID).Title("ACOID").Width(50).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text text-left" });
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.V22MedicalRiskScore).Width(10).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text text-right" }).HeaderTemplate("<span class='kh-Grid-tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='CMS-HCC V22 Risk Score'>CMS-HCC V22 RS</span>");
                            //columns.Bound(p => p.RxRiskScore).Width(20).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text text-right" }).HeaderTemplate("<span class='kh-Grid-tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='RxRiskScore'>RxRscore</span>");
                        })
          .Excel(excel => excel
                        .FileName("")
                        .Filterable(true)
                        .AllPages(true))

                        .Filterable()
                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBoundPreservePatientGrid"))
                        .Filterable()
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(10)
                                                            .Read(read => read.Action("RiskScorePatientData", "Reports", new { ACOName = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.CurrAcoName) }))
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                        )

                         .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                         .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
)
@*}*@
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking for? Are you asking how to configure a grid at runtime with a custom set of columns and then the data is bound to that or do you always know what your columns are? Also what is happening with your current implementation. I am happy to help but as I said it is not clear what you are after.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I want configure a grid at runtime with a custom set of columns as i am not aware of what my columns are !

Comment: try the demo's here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/binding-kendoui-grid-to-dynamic-column-and-values#kwwWB4EyNUazUVtGsJyXlg this explains how to bind to a table or dynamic object. I personally find the data table approach is nicer.

Comment: I changed my Controller part Json(reportRepository.MedicalRiskScorePatientData(User.EmailId, ACOName).ToDataSourceResult(request)); 

it displays only column name in horizontal direction column value is not displayed

Comment: What data is being generated as part of the request when you look at something fiddler? Also are you getting any console errors being thrown.

Comment: NO iam not getting any error

Comment: so what is actually being returned from the read action?

Comment: the header is binding in column

Comment: in the action: `Read(read => read.Action("RiskScorePatientData", "Reports", new { ACOName = "Florida Physician Trust" }))` what data is actually being returned. Is it your `column header` data or the actual data you want to present back to the grid? Also are the column headers in the returned dataset the same as the ones you are binding to the grid?

Comment: I also noticed  the name of the grid should be one word as this is used to identify it so rather than `.Name("N Florida Physicians Trust")` it should be something like: `.Name("NFloridaPhysiciansTrust")`.

Comment: I have changed the view part and I hope you can get now what i am doing